# Ez Publish Class with 3 children how to fetch only one?

Tags: html, ezpublish

So i'm using ez Publish. And i have a contact folder with 3 children classes.

I defined in the head:

```
{    $contact_node_id = 258
$contact_classes = array('dnd_locations','dnd_textblock','dnd_contactform')
$contact_folder = fetch( 'content', 'node', hash( 'node_id', $contact_node_id ) )
$contact_children = array()
$contact_children_count=fetch_alias( 'children_count', hash( 'parent_node_id', 258,
                                        'class_filter_type', 'include',
                                        'class_filter_array', $contact_classes ) )
}

{if $contact_children_count}
    {set
    $contact_children = fetch_alias( 'children', hash( 'parent_node_id', $contact_node_id,
                                        'offset', 0,
                                        'sort_by', array( 'priority', true() ),
                                        'class_filter_type', 'include',
                                        'class_filter_array', $contact_classes,
                                        'limit', 100 ) )
    }
{/if}
```

To get the content i use:

```
    {if $contact_children_count}
    {foreach $contact_children as $index => $child }
        {node_view_gui content_node=$child view=full}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

But then it fetches the content of all 3 children. How can i define that it should only fetch the first??

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3):

'Limit' in your fetch function is what you are looking for.

So Instead of 100, use 1. That's it